# In Alfresco, how can I test if a NodeRef and/or FileInfo object refers to a binary file?

Tags: alfresco

In Alfresco, how can I test if a NodeRef and/or FileInfo object refers to a binary file? (ie. node.isBinary())

Thanks, that does help.
I have also been trying to follow examples of reading the file contents using ContentService, but I con't seem to get the ContentService available in my code.
Can anyone the steps for making ContentService available?
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

First up, see if it's of type `cm:content` or not:

```
QName nodeType = nodeService.getType(nodeRef);
if (! dictionaryService.isSubClass(nodeType, ContentModel.TYPE_CONTENT)) {
    // Not content, so content can't be binary
   return false;
}
```

Next up, you need to fetch the `Content` node property, which'll be a ContentData object, and finally check the mimetype on that.

```
ContentData contentData = (ContentData)nodeService.getProperty(
                                            nodeRef, ContentModel.PROP_CONTENT);
String mimetype = contentData.getMimetype();
if (mimetype == null) {
    // No idea...
} else if (mimetype.startsWith("text/")) {
    // Shouldn't be binary
    return false;
} else {
    // Most likely binary, but there are a few unusual mimetypes
    //  not under the text/* range that are text...
    return true;
}
```

You don't need to go to the ContentService or read the actual content, just get the metadata stored for it